# How can create pojo class for mp3 files stored in assets android?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

- Where should i store my mp3's assets or raw?
- what my kotlin data/pojo class should have? filepath how to calculate?
- how can i create path to be stored in data class and again retireve in recyler adapter with name pased in pojo class?

I want to store multiple images and mp3 and want to use viewmodel too

update:

My Pojo class:

```
data class SoundsModel(
    var name: String,
    var imagePath: String,
    var filePath: String
)
```

My adapter binder:

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {

```
holder.binding.ivSound.setImageDrawable(context.resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.bg_mountains))
holder.binding.tvSound.text = modelList[position].name
```

}

My array:

```
lateinit var soundList: ArrayList<SoundsModel>
soundList= arrayListOf()
    soundList.add(SoundsModel("Rain Sound","bg_mountains","name"))
    soundList.add(SoundsModel("Rain Sound","bg_mountains","name"))
    soundList.add(SoundsModel("Rain Sound","bg_mountains","name"))
    soundList.add(SoundsModel("Rain Sound","bg_mountains","name"))
    soundList.add(SoundsModel("Rain Sound","bg_mountains","name"))
    soundList.add(SoundsModel("Rain Sound","bg_mountains","name"))
```

Comment: I tried using image in drawble , but when i tried to get image, liek resources.getDrawable(r.drawblle.name) it shows doesnt exist

Comment: getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.filename) i know this fun, but how can i create path of it and use it for next time? what is proper way i dont know

Comment: You don't create a path of it.  Resources don't have paths.

Comment: yeah so what should i do? after all search of stackoverflow im only getting we cant create a path, then what should i do for model class of mp3 files? and how to retrive in recylerview what is good approach?

Answer (score 0):

Assets vs raw-  if you have lots of them, assets.  Raw would only be used if you have a very small set of them you never expect to change.  I'd really only be using resources if there's some part of the resource system, like switching them out for different locales, that you need to take advantage of.

What should your pojo have?  You need to explain that better-  what do you want a POJO for and how is it going to be used.  If you just want to reference an asset or resource you'd use the name (for assets) or id (for resources).  No need to make a class for either.

What's the path?  Neither of them have a path.  WebViews have a hack in them that uses a path to assets and converts that into calls to asset manager, but by neither of them have paths that would be recognized if you tried to make a File() object.  For resources you just use R.raw.resource_name.  For assets you use AssetManager.open.

Comment: pls check question again i have added details, the way i want to use is there will be list of model class which have name but how to access them is issue and how to add in model